# Server 2008 R2 Virtual Key Licensing

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

As per Microsoft's [website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949748), when you purchase Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, you're entitled to 4 virtual machines to run on that host. I know that if you purchase the product as a FPP or as OEM, you are provided with a seperate virtual key, but what happens if the product was purchased as another type (e.g. volume licensing)? Can you use the same key as the host when activating the VMs?

Comment: Not necesarily, this is techncal.

Answer (score 1):

Licening is separate from keys used quite often. You will find that VL licensing People either use MAK (Multi Activation Keys) or have a local KMS. When MS makes areview, all you do is Count licenses licensed vs. licesnes used, the acutal keys are not that relevan in this case.

I run under SPLA, and all my Windows Auto activates using a KMS.

As a volume licensing customer you normally get ONE key for ALL your uses (ok, 2+ - a MAK and a KMS, but you can ask for more MAK keys) and then use them "as you see fit" within the legal Setup.